# Can't scroll over amcharts chart on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

So I have a chart that spans 100% when on mobile but when trying to scroll the screen by touching the graph and swiping it simply triggers an event instead of scrolling. For instance if I try to scroll over a pie chart it will bring up the bubble of the pie slice.

Is there an event I could disable to alleviate this issue?

Comment: I guess I should mention this is with the amcharts js plugin

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Just posted the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix was to set an option in the chart

`"panEventsEnabled": false`

Answer (score 1):

For line graphs I had to use a combination of the two below:

```
"panEventsEnabled": false
```

From
http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptstockchart/PanelsSettings#panEventsEnabled

and

```
"pan":true
```

From
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor#pan

Hope it helps!